# Upload vimeo video with Laravel 8.x

Tags: laravel, vimeo

I am testing vimeo with vimeo basic account and Laravel 8.x / guzzle in order to pay for a pro licence.

I am trying to implement a form-based video upload approch. According to the documents available to vimeo website, the first step consists in sending a post request to /me/videos then i will receive a response that will contain an HTML form in the upload.form field. Yet, the request status code is correct (201 : created).

My issue is that i don't see this field (upload.form) in the api server response (i have made a dd($response)).

Here is the code in my controller:

```
 $response =  Http::withToken('xxxxxxx')->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type'=>'application/json',
            'Accept'=>'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            ])->post('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos', [
            'upload'=>[                
                'size'=>$request->file->getsize(),
                'approch'=>'post',
            ]
        ]);
```

Can a person help me solve this problem?

The link of the documentation i have read is: [Working with Video Uploads](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos) and other API references.

I really need your help please

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. You are required to make an effort yourself and if you get stuck somewhere we're here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all.
I have tried the same request with postman and it has allowed me to understand that the instruction dd($response) does not give me all the informations contained in the server's response but just some informations in the headers.

To see what i wanted i have used one of these instructions:

```
dd($response->body());
// or
dd($response->json())
```

For example to obtain the HTML form provided by vimeo API, i have to use this instruction:

```
$response->json()['upload']['form'];
```

So i consider closed, this ticket.